# Does $x \ge s \le t\ge y$ $\implies x \ge y$

Tags: inequality

Does $x \ge s \le t\ge y$ $\implies x \ge y$?

If not a counterexample would suffice.

Thanks.

Comment: $1 \geqslant 0 \leqslant 3 \geqslant 2$, but $1 < 2$

Comment: What did you try? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2\ge 1\le 4\ge 3$ but $2<3$.